# Почему video игнорирует размер контейнера родителя?

Tags: html, css

Почему видео не подчиняется размерам контейнера родителя?

HTML

```
<div class="video">
  <video autoplay muted>
    <source src="img/deep.mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.video{
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
video{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Он не игнорирует, просто Вы для этого `div` с классом `.video` задали конкретную ширину 450px. А видео заполняет всё доступное пространство по этой ширине.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не игнорирует, подчиняется:

```css
.video{
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
video{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  
  <video autoplay muted>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
</div>
```

Можно еще управлять заполнение видео в блоке с помощью `object-fit` [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit):

```css
.video {
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">

  <video autoplay muted>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо и прошу прощения за бесполезный вопрос. Моя ошибка была в том что совсем в другом месте я задал position: absolute тэгу video